# Need help with an induction proof involving a summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

Before we get started, yes this is homework. please only give me hints so that i can solve this thing myself. thanks for the help.

here's what I got so far:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep going!  You have a common $10^{P}$ in your last two terms, so take that out, and see where it leads...

Comment: wow rofl. 5 hours looking at that not to notice it... thanks!!!